# <ToggleButton> onClickListener - Creating and deleting buttons?

Tags: java, android, button, togglebutton

Is it possible to create and delete buttons upon toggling an onClickListener?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
    Button minuskegle, minuskugle, pluskugle, pluskegle, plusmidkegle, minusmidkegle;
ToggleButton toggle;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.bRedGreen);
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            pluskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);
            minuskugle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBallhole);

            pluskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);
            minuskegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKegle);

            plusmidkegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKeglemid);
            minusmidkegle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bKeglemid);

        if(toggle.isChecked())
        {
            minuskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redballinhole);
            minuskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.redkegle);
            minusmidkegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.midkegleminus);
        }

        else 
        {
            pluskugle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.whiteballinhole);
            pluskegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kegleb);
            plusmidkegle.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.midkegleplus);
        }

        }

    });
}
```

I need it to create buttons upon if(toggle.isChecked())

else

delete them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy enough :)

Find the parent view in which you want to insert your new button, create a button, insert button into view :

```
RelativeLayout parentView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);
Button buttonTest = new Button(MyActivity.this);
parentView.addView(buttonTest);
```

MyActivity.this is necessary because you are inside the click function and this does not refer to the activity.

Comment: Cheers, how do i delete it them again then?
And how do i define the contents of the button upon creation?

If i for example want it to inherit this:

                android:id="@+id/bKeglemid"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:background="@drawable/midkegleplus"
                Imageview.Scaletype="fill_parent"

Comment: parentView.removeView(buttonTest); ... Don't forget to mark as an answer if it worked for you !!

Comment: I'm still in the very beginning phase of programming.

in this (myactivity.this)
what am i supposed to write instead of myactivity?
I tried with activity name of the app, in both normal and capital letters.

Comment: MyActivity should be replaced by the name of your Activity using the exact same case as your activity filename. So in this case, it is assuming you are working on class MyActivity {} in the file MyActivity.java